# UITableViewCell has a choppy row insertion/deletion animation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm currently deleting and inserting rows based on the content within a class which is called a content builder. An example of this can be seen below.

```
func stateDidChange(id: String, _ state: Bool) {

    switch id {
    case ConfigureExerciseContentBuilderKeys.accessory.rawValue:
        exerciseProgramming.isAccessory = state

        if state {

            if let customIncrementsItemIndex = self.configureExerciseContentBuilder.getContent().firstIndex(where: { ($0 as? FormLabelTextFieldItem)?.id == ConfigureExerciseContentBuilderKeys.increment.rawValue }),
               let syncedWorkoutsItemIndex = self.configureExerciseContentBuilder.getContent().firstIndex(where: { ($0 as? ExerciseSyncedWorkouts)?.id == ConfigureExerciseContentBuilderKeys.syncedWorkouts.rawValue }) {
                self.configureExerciseContentBuilder = ConfigureExerciseContentBuilder(type: type, exerciseProgramming: exerciseProgramming)

                let incrementsIndexPath = IndexPath(item: customIncrementsItemIndex, section: 0)
                let syncedIndexPath = IndexPath(item: syncedWorkoutsItemIndex, section: 0)
                let spacerIndexPath = IndexPath(item: syncedWorkoutsItemIndex + 1, section: 0)

                self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [incrementsIndexPath, syncedIndexPath, spacerIndexPath], with: .automatic)
                self.tableView.endUpdates()
            }
        } else {

            self.configureExerciseContentBuilder = ConfigureExerciseContentBuilder(type: type, exerciseProgramming: exerciseProgramming)

            if let customIncrementsItemIndex = self.configureExerciseContentBuilder.getContent().firstIndex(where: { ($0 as? FormLabelTextFieldItem)?.id == ConfigureExerciseContentBuilderKeys.increment.rawValue }),
               let syncedWorkoutsItemIndex = self.configureExerciseContentBuilder.getContent().firstIndex(where: { ($0 as? ExerciseSyncedWorkouts)?.id == ConfigureExerciseContentBuilderKeys.syncedWorkouts.rawValue }) {

                let incrementsIndexPath = IndexPath(item: customIncrementsItemIndex, section: 0)
                let syncedIndexPath = IndexPath(item: syncedWorkoutsItemIndex, section: 0)
                let spacerIndexPath = IndexPath(item: syncedWorkoutsItemIndex + 1, section: 0)

                self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                self.tableView.insertRows(at: [incrementsIndexPath, syncedIndexPath, spacerIndexPath], with: .automatic) // Insert into the index of where the accessory row was/is
                self.tableView.endUpdates()
            }
        }

    default:
        break
    }
}
```

The rows are successfully deleted and inserted based on the logic above and I used the automatic parameter so that the tableview can handle this in the best way.

It's also worth noting that within the tableviewcell autolayout is used on elements within them and also I've configured the row height within the tableview to be dynamic based on its contents.

But for some reason I seem to be getting a weird choppy animation when I delete or insert rows for the green box that you can see in the video attached. Does anyone have any pointers/ideas as to why this may be happening?

[Link to video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UIDsUah7REI&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: Did you give a height constant to your green box view? This happens when height of cell auto adjust itself during animation, i.e. it tries with the estimated height for cell as row height is dynamic.

Comment: @sinner Yep and i also pinned it to all edges within the content view

Comment: Do you set an estimated row height or implement the `estimatedHeightForRow` delegate method?  If not, you should do this.